# Google Gauge (Data Chart Visualization) not loading in page called by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having some issues integrating the Google Gauge chart visualization into my site. The example code they give is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Memory', 80],
      ['CPU', 55],
      ['Network', 68]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 400, height: 120,
      redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

By itself, this code works fine when a div with the id chart_div is in the body. However, each page on my site is called by ajax using loadandsetactive and loaded into a content div under a "static" header. When the same code is entered into the head of any of these pages, it fails to load. There is no error, no blank chart, or any other sign that the script even attempted to load. An example of how the pages are loaded into a content div is:

```
        <li class="menuItem" id="mypage">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadAndSetActive('mypage.html', '#content', '#mypage');" >
    <img src="myimage.png" width="100%" height="auto"/>My Page</a></li>
```

Pages are then loaded into the aforementioned content div under the header. The site is almost completely finished, but I just can't seem to get this gauge to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, once the user logs in, the ajax call automatically loads the dashboard where I am trying to draw the chart in a div. The mypage is a full html file with it's own tag   etc. Unfortunately, my PHP and HTML/CSS are much better than my ajax and jquery.

Comment: I can tell you that my experience with the Charts API taught me that the target element **must** be on the page and visible in order for the chart to draw correctly. You may need to load the new HTML and __then__ call the chart functions.

Comment: I'm calling all the functions from "mypage.html" and the target element is the first div in the body of that page. I've checked the case and spelling of the div id as well (and made sure it's an id, not class, name, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried a `console.log` from `mypage.html` to verify that the JavaScript is being executed?

Comment: I'm just getting in for the day and will do that ASAP.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I checked the console.log and it is showing that the script is running. The response is ok and FireBug shows all of the code. I also tried loading it directly into the target div with a quick $("#divid").load("stuff.html") script, but no change. The target div simply comes up blank. As expected, any text or image manually coded in that div (besides the script) are cleared out when the script runs. Typing stuff.html in the address bar loads a functioning gauge, but .load() returns a blank div.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm just using an iframe to load the gauge from another html file on my site. That seems like it should be unnecessary though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using setOnLoadCallback try calling it inside the google.load itself, below is the code snippet:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages:['gauge'],
  callback: drawChart
});
```